# I'm trying to display images using php while loop from the database, but it is not displaying in a row .what should I do?

Tags: php, html

I have used $row variable that contains database information and I want to repeat the div element with class
"col-md-3 col-sm-6" to repeat it self until the end of array.
I just want that every products details like product's image, name and price
should be display in one line and after 4 products it should display on the next line

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","grocerystore");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_products";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Instamart Grocery Store</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.php " class="navbar-brand">Instamart Grocery</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar"></button>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- <li><a href="setting.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; setting</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; logout</a></li> -->
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <center>
                                <h4>
                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>
                                </h4>
                            </center>
                            <a href="orders.php"> Your Orders</a>
                            <a href="loginform.php"> Log-out</a>
                            <a href="setting.php">Change password</a>
                            <a href="mycart.php">Your cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Let's be Healty together</h1>
            <p>We have best choises of all products</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!-- <div class="thumbnail"> -->
                <div class="caption">
                    <a href="dairy.php">
                        <h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Dairy Products</button></h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!-- <div class="thumbnail"> -->
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="temp"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Fresh Vegetable</button></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!-- <div class="thumbnail"> -->
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Fresh Fruits</button></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!-- <div class="thumbnail"> -->
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Daily Needs</button></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row1">
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $image = $row['img_dir'];
                ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <?php echo"<img src='{$image}'>";?>
                    <div>
                        <h3>
                            <?php echo $row['product_name'];?>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Price:
                            <?php echo $row['price'];?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="cart.php">
                            <button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to cart</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }  ?>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

the images are displaying like this
[image]

Comment: Is this really a MySQL problem, or a e-commerce problem? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to use other class instead of thumbnail (which is bootstrap class already responsive  class) but then I have to write media query for that class.

Comment: I would argue that this is a HTML/CSS problem. First create the layout you want and add some static dummy data (which you can copy from the database). When it looks correct, then add your PHP and dynamically output the images. Easier to take one thing at the time.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I have created the layout for that and it was working perfectly there. but when I add php then it is not working as it worked for the html and css layout

Comment: @M.Eriksson if I comment  <?php echo"<img src='{$image}'>";?> this line then the content is properly in the sequence

Comment: It could be that the images have different heights, which means that their containing elements also will have different heights. That can definitely cause issues like this. Try making all the product blurbs/containers the same height and test.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I have used thumbnail class automatically adjust the size of all elements inside it, also I have made all images size same so that size should not matter

Comment: This looks like problem of older Bootstrap versions, that used `float` to get the columns next to each other. And if not all floated elements in a row are of the same height, then this is simply the kind of effect you get with floating.

Comment: You can probably fix it by adding flex properties to the row, which is what more current BS versions are using anyway. Try adding `.row { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }`, and see if that fixes it without destroying too much else :-)

Comment: @CBroe okay that might be the issue, I will check and update

Comment: @CBroe not solved!!

Comment: Well then give us some proper details, you have not even told us which BS version you are actually using there yet.

Comment: @CBroe I have added whole code, have a look, hope you get my issue now

Comment: @CBroe my issue is solved by adding .row { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; } this. Thank you !!